# How to run C# Console application from SQL Job in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to try out to run my C# console application from SQL Job. So to test it, I simply created a console application and using C# and SMO, wrote few lines to create a database. I could run it successfully and it creates a database in the SQL Server as expected.

Then in IDE, I clicked on `Build-->Publish myProject to E:\myFolder\MakeNewDB24` because that's where my SQL Server resides on.

The above action copied the following files to the specified location i.e., E:\myFolder\MakeNewDB24

- Application Files
- setup.exe
- myProject.application

Then I opened my SQL Server, created a job by 
`rt. clicking Jobs Folder-->New Job`.
I filled all the information in General.
In Steps, I have under Command,

```
\\mySQLServer\myFolder\MakeNewDB24\setup.exe

Type: Operating System(CmdExec)
Run as: SQL Server Agent Service Account
```

I ran the job. It showed the result as "Success"
When I viewed the History,

```
Executed as user: mySQLServer\SYSTEM. The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.
```

I was happy. But when I went to check the database that was supposed to be created, its not available, meaning the SQL JOb didn't do its job to create my db.

I don't know what am I missing here? If anyone has knowledge on this, please kindly share with me. I really really want to see my SQL Job do this work. The reason I m using SQL job is because all of my automation tasks start from here. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you just run the program by double clicking on it after you have copied it to the new location?

Comment: Reaching, but is the job step set to type "Operating system (CmdExec)"? The default is T-SQL. It is also likely you are having issues (again) because SQL Server Agent is not the same as your user account. Finally, why can't the job just run CREATE DATABASE in T-SQL?

Comment: When I double click on setup.exe from the E:\, I get Application Install Security warning. I clicked on Install button. Then it installs it and boom, I could see the db my code created in SQL Server. Please let me know what am I missing. Thanks.

Comment: That application install security warning is going to prevent SQL Server from running this job in the background (and probably leave you with as many orphaned processes as the number of times you started the job). The cmd line program can raise NO DIALOGS and require NO USER INPUT. Make sure you disable UAC and that the program doesn't require any user interaction at all.

Comment: @Aron Bertrand, yes my JOb is set to type "Operating System(CmdExec)". The default might be T-SQL but in my scenario, I m not using any T-SQL to create a db. Instead I m using my c# console application to create a db, which does its job on running from Visual studio. How Do I disable UAC and how do I make sure that the program doesn't require any user interaction- not even installing it from E:\?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem almost certainly has to do with permissions.  You need to check the user id used for running the SQL Server Agent job.  My guess is that it doesn't have permissions somewhere along the line.

The reason that your job returns success is because CMD jobs always return success if they successfully launch the CMD executable.  It has nothing to do with whether or not your code succeeded.

In environments where I don't have to worry about security, I have gotten into the unfortunate habit of giving everything admin privileges, so I don't have to worry about what privileges are needed where.  Good luck.